# Get url path without parameters in Angular2+

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Is there a way to get url path without parameters.

If I have this inside RouterModule:

```
{ path: 'one/two', component: OneTwoComponent }
{ path: 'one/two/:id', component: OneTwoComponent }
```

I need to get string

> "/one/two"

for my NavigationService in both cases, with and without id.

Comment: You need to get that where? In the RouterModule? And what for?  Seems like this question is missing some information.

Comment: I need it inside my SidenavComponent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a code which worked for me in this case.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class NavigationService {

  constructor(
    private router: Router
  ) {

    this.router.events.subscribe((val) => {
      if (val instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        const urlTree = this.router.parseUrl(val.url);
        const urlSegments = urlTree.root.children['primary'].segments.map(segment => segment.path);
        const url = (`/${urlSegments[0]}/${urlSegments[1]}`);
      }
    });

  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try activated route like this:

`constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }`

Then you can check if there is id param in the route or not and depending on that you can get the route by combining the URLSegments like this:

```
let segmentLength = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.url.length;
let path = '/';
if (this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params['id']) {
  segmentLength--;
}

for (let i = 0; i < segmentLength; i++) {
  path += this.activatedRoute.snapshot.url[i].path + '/';
}
console.log(path);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

`constructor(private router: Router) {}`

`url:string`

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.url = this.router.url;
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      if (params['id']) {
        this.url = this.url.substr(0, this.url.lastIndexOf("\/"));
      }
    })
  }
```

Comment: This code is working great but sometimes there is no id in url just '/one/two'. In that case it is not working. In that case it retunrs '/one'.

Comment: In that case you can check if the route has any param, only then get the substring

Comment: @IvanTanasijevic Updated the answer, please check